# Searching for a string in an Arraylist, without having to input the whole string

Tags: java, string, search, arraylist

I have written a class

```
Book(String title, String author)
```

And then i have another class Register, containing an arraylist with all the books.

I am now writing a method in which i want to be able to find a book by searching on the Author, but the difficulty here is that this search method as to be able to find the book without having to input the whole title. HOW?

Here is all that i have written:

```
public class Book {
     private String title; // titel
     private String author; // författare

     /** Skapar en bok med författaren author och titeln title */   
     public Book(String author, String title) {     
         this.author = author;     
         this.title = title;  
     }

     /** Returnerar namnet på författaren */  
     public String getAuthor() {    
         return author; 
     }

     /** Returnerar titeln */  
     public String getTitle() {  
         return title; 
     }

     /** Returnerar en sträng som består av bokens författare och titel */
     public String toString() {
         return author + "\t" + title; 
     }
}
```

.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Dialog {

    /** Skapar ett Dialog-objekt fšr hantering av popup-dialogrutor. */
    public Dialog() {
    }

    /** Visar en dialogruta med hjŠlptexten s dŠr anvŠndaren skall mata in ett 
      * heltal som returneras.
      * Om anvŠndaren anger ett felaktigt vŠrde eller klickar pŒ "avbryt" sŒ 
      * returneras Integer.MAX_VALUE.
      */
    public int readInt(String s) {
        String in = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(s);
        try {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(in);
            return i;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
    }

    /** Visar en dialogruta med hjŠlptexten s dŠr anvŠndaren skall mata in en 
      * teckenstrŠng som returneras.
      * Om anvŠndaren klickar pŒ "avbryt" sŒ returneras null.
      */
    public String readString(String s) {
        String in = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(s);
        if (in == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return in.trim();
        }
    }

    /** Visar en dialogruta med textstrŠngen s. */
    public void printString(String s) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s, "",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Register {
    private ArrayList<Book> reg;     // registret skall lagras i en ArrayList 

    /** Skapar ett tomt register*/
    public Register(){
        reg = new ArrayList<Book>();
    }

    /**Sätter in boken bok sist i Registret reg*/
    public void addBook(Book bok) {
        reg.add(bok);
    }

    /**Tar bort alla böcker av en viss författare author*/
    public void removeAuthor(String author1) {
        for(int i = 0; i<reg.size(); i++){
            if(reg.get(i).getAuthor().equals(author1)){
                reg.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }

    /**Söka upp alla böcker som gäller för en viss författare.
    Det skall räcka att man anger en del av författarnamnet. 
    Samtliga böcker vars författare passar in skall presenteras med både författare och titel. */
    public Book searchBook(String Author2){
        ArrayList<Book> kopia = new ArrayList <Book>();
        for(int i = 0; i<reg.size();i++){
            for(String string : )
        }
    }

    //...  Konstruktor och alla metoderna för registerhanteringen   

    /** Läser registret från filen med namn fileName. */ 
    public void readFromFile(String fileName) { 
        //...  Se ledning för filhanteringen sist i uppgiften 
    }

    /** Sparar registret på fil med namnet fileName. */
    public void writeToFile(String fileName) {   
        //...  Se ledning för filhanteringen sist i uppgiften  
    }
}
```

Comment: How about doing a regex search and do a pattern matching on whatever criteria you might have?

Comment: You'll need to give better detail - do you want to find the string in any part of the string, or only the beginning? You could use regular expressions to do this, but alternatively, you could look at stuff like string matching algorithms (Boyer-Moore or Knuth-Pratt).

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();

  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);

  for (Book book:list) {
    if (p.matcher(book.getTitle()).matches()) {
      matches.add(book);
    }
  }
```

perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `ArrayList.contains()`, you'll have to override `equals()` to compare books using their `author` fields. However, this limits you to only searching by author.

If you want to be more flexible in how you find things, I think you might want to consider multiple `HashMaps` that map authors to sets of books and titles to specific books, or something like that. It's a bit more awkward to set that up though...

Edit: Looks I might have misinterpreted your question, but I'll leave this here in case it's helpful in some other way...

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think i have something going on, by using the indexOf in string, i can now find the strings that match what im searching for, the problem now is that i want to return multiple books, but it will only allow to return one book.

  public Book searchBook(String Author2){
   ArrayList<Book> kopia = new ArrayList <Book>();
  for(int i = 0; i<reg.size();i++){
   if(reg.get(i).getAuthor().toLowerCase().indexOf(Author2.toLowerCase()) >= 0){
    kopia.add(reg.get(i));
   }
  }
   for(int k = 0; k<kopia.size(); k++){
    return kopia.get(k);
   }
  }

Comment: In that case, you could return the entire `ArrayList`

Answer (score 0):

1) pass title as a parameter to the method from where you are calling

2)create a list only once at the method start

3)iterate each reg object using for loop

4)take each book using reg.get(i) and get the title of it and compare it with passed string(which is a title which we are serching) and use regular expression for match.

5)if match is found , add that book into the list

6)return the final list of matched books

```
 public List<Book> searchBook(String title){
        ArrayList<Book> kopia = new ArrayList <Book>();
       for(int i = 0; i<reg.size();i++){
           if(reg.get(i).getTitle().matches("(.*)"+title+"(.*)")){
               kopia.add(reg.get(i));
           }

       }
       return kopia;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think i have something going on, by using the indexOf in string, i can now find the strings that match what im searching for, the problem now is that i want to return multiple books, but it will only allow to return one book.

  public Book searchBook(String Author2){
   ArrayList<Book> kopia = new ArrayList <Book>();
  for(int i = 0; i<reg.size();i++){
   if(reg.get(i).getAuthor().toLowerCase().indexOf(Author2.toLowerCase()) >= 0){
    kopia.add(reg.get(i));
   }
  }
   for(int k = 0; k<kopia.size(); k++){
    return kopia.get(k);
   }
  }

Comment: use my above answered method..it returns multiple books in the form of arraylist..let me know for any issues..

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
public List<Book> searchBook(String Author2){
    List<Book> kopia = new ArrayList <Book>();
    for(Book book : reg){
        if(book.getAuthor().equalsIgnoreCase(Author2) || book.getTitle().toLowerCase().indexOf(Author2.toLowerCase()) != -1){
            kopia.add(book);
        }
    }
    return kopia;
}
```

This is just to keep it simple. You can use regex as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think i have something going on, by using the indexOf in string, i can now find the strings that match what im searching for, the problem now is that i want to return multiple books, but it will only allow to return one book.

  public Book searchBook(String Author2){
   ArrayList<Book> kopia = new ArrayList <Book>();
  for(int i = 0; i<reg.size();i++){
   if(reg.get(i).getAuthor().toLowerCase().indexOf(Author2.toLowerCase()) >= 0){
    kopia.add(reg.get(i));
   }
  }
   for(int k = 0; k<kopia.size(); k++){
    return kopia.get(k);
   }
  }

Comment: If its just one book you can change the return type to Book and in the if statement you could return nook instead of adding this to kopia.